# What does this statement " Object.prototype" do?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, indexof

```
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
```

Can anyone tell me what is the above code doing?

Comment: Just curious, where did you find this?

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it down:

```
Object.prototype
```

This gives us the JavaScript object which is the prototype of the `Object` variable. What's a prototype? Allow me to quote from Yehuda Katz's excellent [blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/) (well worth a read):

> If you try to look up a key on an object and it is not found,
>   JavaScript will look for it in the prototype. It will follow
>   the “prototype chain” until it sees a null value. In that case,
>   it returns undefined.

Next, we have:

```
Object.prototype.toString
```

This returns the `toString` function on `Object`'s prototype. JavaScript functions can be called using their `call` function. Here's a couple examples:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call("foo")  # => "[object String]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(5)      # => "[object Number]"
```

So its basically just a generic toString function, that returns a string describing whatever you give as an argument to `call`. Note that in these examples, the arguments are Objects themselves, so they return strings describing themselves as object. What if we pass it `window.HTMLElement`?

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement)  # => "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
```

So now we see it is returning a string that contains the substring `"Constructor"`, meaning it is likely an object which constructs HTML elements. Finally we can understand the full expression:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor')  # => 19
```

Since `"Constructor"` is a substring, `indexOf` returns 19, which is > 0. So basically, this expression appears to check whether or not `window.HTMLElement` identifies itself using the suffix "Constructor", which I guess may be some kind of browser identification check.

(Note: while writing this, I tested evaluating these expressions using Safari's Web Inspector console, but you could also use Chrome or other browsers' consoles for testing things like this.)

Answer (score 2):

- `Object` is the class (constructor) from which (almost) all types in javascript inherit.
- `Object.prototype` is the object that can be found in the prototype chain of almost all objects.
- `Object.prototype.toString` is the method that gets called on objects that don't override it.
- `.call`, when called on a function, calls the function with its first argument as the context. `func.call(a)` is similar to `a.func=func; a.func()`. The difference is that while `undefined.toString()` is a `TypeError`, `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)` works perfectly fine.
- `HTMLElement` is a class from which HTML elements inherit. However, this is not required by the specification, and is not true in Internet Explorer, where HTML elements don't have a prototype and the `HTMLElement` constructor does not exist there. Since `window` is the global object in browser environment, `window.HTMLElement` is the same as `HTMLElement` *if* not shadowed by a local variable, and *if* it exists. If it doesn't exist, reading `HTMLElement` throws a `ReferenceError` while `window.HTMLElement` returns `undefined`.
- So, `Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement)` is the same as `HTMLElement.toString()` *except* it works in IE and uses the right `toString`. It always returns a `String`.
- `indexOf` is a String function that finds the first occurence of its substring, returning `-1` if the substring is not present. `.indexOf('Constructor') > 0` checks if the string contains, and does not start with, `"Constructor"`.

So, this method determines if `toString` contains `"Constructor"` when called on `HTMLElement`. [The specification mandates that](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2):

> ...
>   4) Let class be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of O.
>   5) Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "[object ", class, and "]".

Thus, this checks if `HTMLElement`'s `[[class]]` is `Constructor`.

Finally the check result is assigned to the variable `isSafari`. This indicates in which environments this is true. The author of this code assumes that the return value contains `"Constructor"` in Safari, in every version of Safari, and only in Safari.

For reference, in Chrome, `Object.prototype.toString.call(HTMLElement)` returns `"[object Function]"`.